# Subprocess not run in python cgi script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, cgi

I have issue while running subprocess in Python CGI script.

I am going to run python file as subprocess in python CGI script.

`script.py`

```
#!enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()

import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "/usr/bin/python3", "test.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

`test.py`

```
f.open("test.txt", "a")
f.write("This is test")
f.close()
```

If I run `script.py` in console, it creates `test.txt` file successfully.
But If I run it on browser with Python CGI, it cannot create `test.txt`.

I thought, it can be caused by permission, so I tried to create `test.txt` in `script.py` directly, not on 'test.py', it is created successfully.

So, main issue is Python CGI script cannot run subprocess.

I cannot get any error while running on browser as Python CGI script.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please if sudo does not work, look in the system log. There can be messages that help you with the debugging. The files are in `/var/log` and if you list by time `ls -t` you will see which ones changed just now.

First try without sudo. Make your file in a place where it does not need sudo permission like `/tmp/test.txt`. Then you know if the problem is sudo or something else.

Comment: It is created successfully without `sudo`.
Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe you do not need sudo at all when writing to the "real" location. If you do need sudo then maybe you need the NOPASSWD option. You can Google for the details if you need. (That isn't really a Python problem.)

Comment: I changed writing file directory permission for www-data user to CRUD.
So, it can be successfully created without sudo?